# javascript accessing memory mapping with typedArray

Tags: javascript, c, memory-mapped-files

I need a mechanism to access some memory loaded by a C application using javascript.

For simiplicity the data stored in the memory is a char buffer which will be modified by the C publisher application and it should be read by javascript. I know this can be done in C using various means but i am not sure how to do this in javascript.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. I am working on a low latency client subscriber/publisher application. I have already looked in to typedArrays but i need to access a specific memory mapped by C application. Ideally want access to the memory may be via a pointer(no pointer in javascript though)

Comment: Hello, can you show us what you have tried till now ? Perhaps [this can help you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Comment: I need to access memory owned(but shared) by some other process using javascript

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language. Therefore you can only access the memory of the objects you have created since the JS Engine will handle the memory assignment for you.

Comment: Can i call a C program inside javascript to get the value from the memory and pass it to javascript? Any other way ofpossibility/mechanism? or any other means of IPC communication to reduce access times for low latency realtime front end?

Comment: No, JavaScript cannot access anything outside the browser.